# Compilation of restclient-cpp on Cygwin does not build shared libraries

Tags: c++, cygwin

I'm attempting to use [restclient-cpp](https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp) on cygwin; however, when I attempt to compile and install the library, I get the following message:

```
    libtool: warning: undefined symbols not allowed in x86_64-unknown-cygwin shared
libraries; building static only
```

Indeed, my program compiles up until the point when ld attempts to link the executable, with a string of errors effectively all saying:

```
    undefined reference to `RestClient::post(std::string const&, std::string const&,
std::string const&)'
    relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `RestClient::post(
std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any possible resolution for this?

I'm compiling on cygwin with GCC 6.1.0, libtool 2.4.6

EDIT: Submitted Github issue at https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp/issues/55, perhaps author of library will have an answer.

Comment: do you know what is providing `RestClient::post` ?

Comment: restclient-cpp should be; however, the shared library doesn't get built, and thus, can't be linked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all symbols in the library are available, 
you need to add on the relevant Makefile.am
the flag  `-no-undefined` to the proper `your_lib_la_LDFLAGS`

See man of libtool for `-no-undefined`

Comment: I've tried this; however, it seems to me that it merely suppresses the warning. The dynamic link libraries still don't get built.

Comment: If fails as there are missing definitions the warning/error should be there.